# three.js Move and Rotate a Mesh with Camera and physi.js

Tags: javascript, three.js, physics

I try to move an object in Three.js with Physi.js.
the camera is connected to the mesh that is moving.
I move it with .setLinearVelocity();

### and I rotate it with .setAngularVelocity();

The problem is that I can look in the rotation direction but
when I move forward it will not move in the destination i am looking at.
Thanks for help.

here my walk code:

//mover box

```
var geoMover = new THREE.BoxGeometry(20,20);
var matMover = new Physijs.createMaterial(new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({color: 0xff00E3, specular: 0xffffff, shininess: 60}),.0,.2);
var mover = new Physijs.CapsuleMesh(geoMover, matMover,1);
mover.position.x =0;
mover.position.y = 30;
mover.position.z = 0;
mover.setAngularFactor(THREE.Vector3(0,0,0));
scene.add(mover);
mover.add(camera);
```

//render

```
function render(){

    renderer.clear();


    camera.lookAt(scene.position);

    walk();

    renderer.render(scene, camera);
    requestAnimationFrame(render);
}


render();
```

//walk

```
function walk(){

    //EVENTS lauschen
    var delta = clock.getDelta();

    var physisMove = 10;

    if(keyboard.pressed('left')){
        mover.setAngularVelocity({z:0,y:1,x:0});
        istMoveLeft = true;
    }

        if(keyboard.pressed('up')){
            mover.setLinearVelocity({z: -physisMove, y:0,x:0});
            isMoveForward = true;
        }

        if(keyboard.pressed('right')){
            mover.setAngularVelocity({z:0,y:-1,x:0});
            isMoveRight = true;
        }

        if(keyboard.pressed('down')){
            mover.setLinearVelocity({z: physisMove, y:0,x:0});
            isMoveBackward = true;
        }

    document.addEventListener("keyup", function(event){
      var code = event.keyCode;
        if(code == 38) mover.setLinearVelocity({z:0, y:0,x:0});
        if(code == 40) mover.setLinearVelocity({z:0, y:0,x:0});
        if(code == 37){
            mover.setLinearVelocity({z:0, y:0,x:0});
            mover.setAngularVelocity({z:0,y:0,x:0});
        }
        if(code == 39){
            mover.setLinearVelocity({z:0, y:0,x:0});
            mover.setAngularVelocity({z:0,y:0,x:0});
        }

    });
    mover.setAngularFactor({z:0,x:0,y:0});

    /*
    document.addEventListener('keyup', function(event){
        var code = event.keyCode;
        if(code == 37) istMoveLeft = false;
        if(code == 38) isMoveForward = false;
        if(code == 39) isMoveRight = false;
        if(code == 40) isMoveBackward = false;

    });
    */
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I hope that will help: https://github.com/WhitestormJS/whitestorm.js/blob/beta/src/modules/controls/FirstPersonModule.js

I recommend you to try [whitestomjs](https://github.com/WhitestormJS/whitestorm.js) because of it seems like it already has everything you need (Physi.js + Three.js)